# I want to extract a string from the current exception thrown in a java program

Tags: java, string, error-handling, exception

I am calling a method from a third party jars whose class file is not accessible to me. So for some cases it throws exception logs and I want to extract string from the current log dynamically.

This is the java  program method which throws exception

```
public String runLayoutTest(final String xmlFile){
    try{
        String gettingValue = "novalue";
        boolean errorFlag = perform("runLayoutTest", new Reporter.Reportable() {

        @Override
        public boolean run() throws Exception {
        String layoutXml = null;

        //current directory
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String currentProjectPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + currentProjectPath);

        System.out.println("layoutXml "+xmlFile);
        String x = client.runLayoutTest(currentProjectPath+"\\Excel\\"+xmlFile); 
        System.out.println("******* x ********"+x);
        setX(x);
        return true;
        }
        });

        gettingValue = getX();
        return gettingValue;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("**Any one rule in Layout is failed**");

        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return getX();
    }
}
```

Here the client is a object of the third party jar file , And that is throwing me the exception on some odd cases .

The Exception logs are

```
com.experitest.client.InternalException: Exception caught while executing runLayoutTest: {"rule_1":{"Exists":true},"rule_2":{"Exists":true,"EqualHeight":false},"rule_3":{"AlignedLeft":false}}
at com.experitest.client.JavaClientInternals.executeInternally(JavaClientInternals.java:234)
at com.experitest.client.Client.execute(Client.java:237)
at com.experitest.client.Client.runLayoutTest(Client.java:1475)
at com.igate.framework.NativeDriver$79.run(NativeDriver.java:2753)
at com.igate.framework.Reporter.action(Reporter.java:81)........
```

From this exception I want to extract

```
runLayoutTest: {"rule_1":{"Exists":true},"rule_2":{"Exists":true,"EqualHeight":false},"rule_3":{"AlignedLeft":false}}
```

as a String.

Hence is there any method with which I can dynamically extract such String whenever it occurs.
And I still don't know the reason why my catch method is not getting called.

Comment: You need to `catch` the exception (most likely inside of `run`), and then your String should be part of `e.getMessage()`. Maybe `com.experitest.client.InternalException` has a more specific getter, too.

Comment: Debugger is your friend.

Comment: Your catch is not executed because the exception is caught from the third party library itself. From stack trace, I suspect that exception is handled in client.Client.runLayoutTest(Client.java:1475).

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement this code to attack directly to throwable *detailMessage*. I had to ignore all the hierarchy of classes that extended Exception because someone implemented a horrible *getMessage* method that was being overlapped with web components. In JUnit was no way to define unit test cases because framework's exceptions always tried to translate its error code into the 'session' (web) language...

```
public static Object getThrowableDetailMessage(Throwable throwable) {
try {
    // Tiramos la puerta abajo y pedimos a Throwable que nos pase el código de error
    Field f = Throwable.class.getDeclaredField("detailMessage");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object detailMessageFound = f.get(throwable);
    return detailMessageFound;
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
    //LOG
    return null;
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    //LOG
    return null;
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    //LOG
    return null;
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    //LOG
    return null;
}
}
```

You also can try to replace *Throwable* by *InternalException* and keep the reflection on this level of the hierachy. But like someone is already pointing. Make sure your code is being affected by the Exception you want to inspect.

I have implemented all the catches possible because I wanted to trace a different log for everyone of them. (For debugging and testing overall)

**Note:** My code has been implemented under JDK 1.6_18

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just use `Exception.getMessage()` which will result in

> Exception caught while executing runLayoutTest:
>   {"rule_1":{"Exists":true},"rule_2":{"Exists":true,"EqualHeight":false},"rule_3":{"AlignedLeft":false}}

Below can be used to get the json string. You can then parse the json to get desired data from it

```
String message = e.getMessage();
int colonIndex = message.indexOf(":");
String json = null;
if (colonIndex != -1) {
    json = message.substring(colonIndex + 1);
}
```

Please note that this solution will not work in case of wrapped exception